# How to set Language for entire LWC component like visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, language

In visualforce page we can set the language using language attribute like this.

```
<apex:page id="myr_Page" language="{!userDTO.userlanguage}" >
```

I know that we can use the below way to set the language in LWC. But I want to dynamically set the current logged in user Language.

```
import LOCALE from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';
```

How to do it in LWC? Please help me!